# Keep datagridview row selected

Tags: datagridview

Im looking to have a datagridview row to keep selected after reading information from database but it always go back to the 1st line. If I delete dt.clear I can have the same row selected but the data keeps duplicating

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim row As Integer
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        row = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    End If
    dt.Clear()
    Try
        con.Open()
        sql = "Select * from Requests"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(row).Selected = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask and I am not trying to tell you how to do things, however, regardless of what value the `Timer.Interval` is set to… it is not necessarily the best idea to query the DB using a `Timer` as your posted code does. Can you clarify “why” you want/need to update the grid using a `Timer`?

In addition, as a minimum, it is highly recommended that the code use `Using` statements for the connection to ensure the connection is properly closed.

Your current issue is that the code needs to set the grids `CurentCell` property of the grid to set the “selected” cell/row and you can do this with the current code, however you will not know “which CELL/column” to set as the CurrentCell unless you grab the grids `CurrentCell` before changing the grid’s data source.

You could change the code at the end of the timer tick event to…

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(0)
```

to achieve what you are asking; however, this code is setting column (0) as the current cell and it may have been column (4) or some other column.

You would need to grab the grid’s `CurrentCell` row and column index before the grid’s data source is changed. Then after the grid’s data source has changed… set the grid’s `CurrentCell` property to the previously grabbed indexes. This is shown below.

If you must use a `Timer` for this, then I suggest a little different approach as shown below. It can still be cleaned up; however, the code does implement the `Using` statements as suggested in my comments.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  Dim row = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
  Dim col = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
  GetDataFillGrid()
  If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > row And DataGridView1.Columns.Count > col Then
    DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(col)
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  GetDataFillGrid()
  Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub GetDataFillGrid()
  Dim conString = "YourConnectionString"
  Dim Sql = "YourQueryString"
  Dim dt = New DataTable
  Try
    Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
      con.Open()
      Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, con)
        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
          da.Fill(dt)
          DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End Using
      End Using
    End Using
  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all many thanks for your time! resuming what I'm trying to achieve is creation of 2 apps connect to same database, one to make requests such as breaks and other to approve them (the one I am having issues). I have tried your solution but still getting errors. As you may have understand I am a noob and I am just playing around. I posted the question hoping to be something easy, dont loose more time, I will keep playing around. once more many thanks for your reply and time!

Comment: @António Romano ... It sounds like you have your hands full figuring it out. I am sorry you are getting errors, in my tests, my posted code works as expected. In the future… It helps to know what exact “errors/error messages” you get... comments like “_it doesn’t work,”_ or _”it has errors”_ isn’t much to go on for someone who is trying to help you fix those errors, however, this appears unimportant. Good Luck.

Comment: Dont take me wrong, Im grateful for your help I didnt go deeper into the errors I got with your code because I dont want to take your more of your time for something that Im just playing around and its really not important :) many thanks JohnG!